# Angular does not rerender on Input() change

Tags: javascript, angular

Whatever i do angular does not detect change on talks array. I have a handleSubmit function to send the toolbar. Toolbar use it to send the changes to parent from input field.

My app.component.ts file

```
import { Component, Type, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { getResponse } from '../api/API';

declare module '../api/API' {
  export interface NlpAPI {
    getResponse(data: any): Promise<any>;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {
  talks: string[];
  title: string;
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes);
  }
  constructor() {
    this.talks = [];
    this.title = 'Talks';
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.talks.push('Welcome to ProjectX! How can I help you?');
    this.talks.push('I am a chatbot. I can help you with your queries.');
  }
  handleSubmit(data: any): void {
    this.talks.push(data.talk);
  }
  messageResponse() {
    // @ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'null'.
    const x = document.getElementById('txt').value;
    // @ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'null'.
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML =
      'Your message is ' + '"' + x + '"';
  }
}
```

My app.component.html

```
<!-- Toolbar -->
<app-custom-toolbar [handleSubmit]="handleSubmit"></app-custom-toolbar>

<!-- Highlight Card -->

<app-text-area [talksFromUser]="talks" [title]="title"></app-text-area>
<!-- Bottombar -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My text-area.component.ts file

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-area',
  templateUrl: './text-area.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-area.component.css'],
})
export class TextAreaComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() talksFromUser: string[] = [];
  @Input() title: string = '';
  constructor() {}
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes);
  }
}
```

My text-area.component.html

```
<div class="main-text-area">
  <div *ngFor="let item of talksFromUser">{{ item }}</div>
</div>
```

custom-toolbar.component.ts file

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-toolbar',
  templateUrl: './custom-toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-toolbar.component.css'],
})
export class CustomToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  talks: string[] = [];
  @Input() handleSubmit!: (args: any) => void;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}
  onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    this.handleSubmit(f.value);
    f.resetForm();
  }
}
```

I tried also
this.talks = [...this.talks, data.talk]
Thank you all.

Comment: Definitely change all pushes to spread syntax. Also, you’re not passing any data to handleSubmit it seems?

Comment: I checked with console.log it gets the data correctly and updates state correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues in your code:

- First one, you are calling `handleSubmit("string")` (so `data` is a string), but you are pushing `data.talk`, which is undefined (so `talks` will be `[undefined, undefined, ...]`). To fix it, use `data`:

```
handleSubmit(data: any): void {
    this.talks.push(data); // use "data" instead of "data.talk"
}
```

- Second one, you are using a `AppComponent` method into `CustomToolbarComponent` class. You need to keep the `this` scope of `AppComponent`. Also, you should use arrow functions:

```
handleSubmit = (data: any): void => {
    this.talks.push(data);
}
```